# check if a user exists in a sharepoint site

Tags: powershell, office-365, csom

Is there anyway to check if a use exists in a office 365 site. I am adding meta data to items in a document library and I am using `ensureuser` but if the user is not there I don't want it to be added so before I use ensureuser is there anyway of checking whether the user exists in the site or not? This is a powershell script csom

Answer (score 1):

The [SharePoint Online PowerShell Management Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) lets you query a site and get the users of that site. Searching for the exact user will either return the user record if found or throw a `User not found` exception if the user doesn't exist on the site.

```
$site = Get-SPOSite https://contoso.sharepoint.com
Get-SPOUser -Site $site -LoginName jsmith@contoso.com

DisplayName : Jane Smith
LoginName   : jsmith@contoso.com
IsSiteAdmin : False
IsGroup     : False
Groups      : {}
```

Comment: what do I need to install because its just saying get-spouser is not recognised

Comment: You need to install the management shell. I've added the link to the answer.

Comment: is there not a way to do this with the regular powershell?